# JavaScript: elementFromPoint(x,y)

Tags: javascript, dom

Hey guys, 
I'm writing a Firefox plugin and using the following function:

var obj = page.elementFromPoint(x,y); //x,y are the mouse coordinates

However this function returns the topmost element which lies under the given point.  This isn't good enough for me, I need the most inner element which lies under the given point.  Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: How does the topmost element differ from the inner element?

Comment: By obscuring the element. E.g. when you implement some kind of D'n'D your dragged element obscures the target. Gecko and WebKit support the style `pointer-events: none;` to prevent pointer events on the dragged element, but generally you can only manually search the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gecko and WebKit support the style `pointer-events: none;` to prevent pointer events on the element obscuring the one you want to find, but generally you can only manually search the DOM tree. Or set `display: none;` to the elements you don't want to get before you use `elementFromPoint`, if that is possible in your setup.